# Advice on Purchase model design (with Gateway interaction)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm making a Purchase model that handles site purchases, which will interact with the Payment Gateway. My question is about how to design the interface, whether I should use separate class methods to do the work, or patch into the AR lifecycle with callbacks.

At first I was doing something like Purchase.make_purchase(product, ...), as a class method. But this didn't seem great.

What I'm about to implement is a solution that uses the model lifecycle and callbacks to make the purchase and gateway transaction. Something like this:

```
@purchase = Purchase.new
@purchase.product = product
@purchase.user = current_user

if @purchase.save
else
end
```

I would then have a before_save callback that talks to the gateway:

```
before_save :transfer_funds
```

that can halt save if unsuccessful, setting @purchase.errors[:gateway_error]

I'm not sure this is the best way to go about this. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it yet so I can't give much insight but I'd take a look at [ActiveMerchant](http://activemerchant.org/) if you haven't already.  I'm not sure what your payment gateway is right now, but if you're not using it; you may get a few ideas.

**EDIT** I realize it didn't answer the question, I was just thinking it may give you some ideas if you weren't already using it.

*I don't have direct experience with payment processing so you can take my opinions with a big grain of salt.*

My big consideration with using the life cycle methods is that you may end up having to put extra logic in  your `transfer_funds` method in this case that you may not otherwise need.  For example, if a `Purchase` could be updated at a later time, then you're going to be calling your `transfer_funds` method every time it's updated.

I'm not sure if a `Purchase` has the concept of a pre-authorization followed by an actual charge, but I'd imagine the `transfer_funds` should only be called once?  You may be able to move this to a `before_create` instead but that may only fix this one scenario.

I've also found that moving them to the lifecycle methods can often add a lot more logic into your model than may desirable.  In the past, I've found that being more explicit in a controller action can sometimes save me headaches down the road even if it adds a step for me to do every place I need to `transfer_funds` for example.

I now try to keep my life cycle methods in the model class only related to updating the `ActiveRecord` model itself and not doing much extra work.  If keeping it in your controller is not viable, I'd consider using an [ActiveRecord::Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) to abstract out the logic associated with `transfer_funds`.

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: I AM using active merchant, but that's not the question ;)

Comment: Understood, i updated my answer to give my personal experience with lifecycle methods, hopefully it may give you some ideas.

Comment: I'm 85% done with the model using the life-cycle approach. I have come to the same conclusion as you with the before_create, instead of before save. You can see it here (not completed) http://pastie.org/2541360